# Nested traits / facade in Scala

Tags: scala, scala.js

If you take a look at the Reddit api you get back something like this:

```
{"children": [{"data":{"permalink": "a", "url": "b", "etc": "..."}}]
```

How would I define a Scala trait that represents that?

Something along these lines maybe...?

```
trait RedditSubreddit extends js.Object {
    val children: Array[trait {val permalink: String; val url: String;}]
}
```

Comment: Please update the question to match how you updated my answer. Now my answer is very confusing since it does not match the question any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this.

```
trait RedditPost extends js.Object {
  val permalink: String
  val url: String
}

trait RedditSubreddit extends js.Object {
  val children: js.Array[RedditPost]
}
```

Although, given that Reddit allows arbitrary nesting of sub-posts, the API might more correspond to this:

```
trait RedditPost extends js.Object {
  val permalink: String
  val url: String
  val children: js.Array[RedditPost]
}
```

Or maybe you want to add an `UndefOr` in case the field is not always set:

```
trait RedditPost extends js.Object {
  val permalink: String
  val url: String
  val children: js.UndefOr[js.Array[RedditPost]]
}
```

Comment: So is there no way to nest the traits, rather than spin up 2 traits. Just feel like with large applications with countless api endpoints.. Ill have more traits than actual code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to feel there is something fundamentally off with scala.js. I mean it's a brilliant idea and a monumental work, but still, some things are either untyped or too cumbersome to write.

Comment: @gurghet yeah, tend to agree.. Just nothing else out there that's similar... PureScript, but that's too Haskelly, TypeScript, that has like no functional unless you run Lodash or something.... Maybe we just wait for Scala to mature, or see a "DefinitlyTyped / Typings" evolve for Scala.

Comment: You can nest the traits in the companion object of another trait. But nesting the trait has a different meaning in standard Scala (the inner type is associated with an *instance* of the outer type). While we could theoretically change this for JS types, it is practically hard to achieve, as it probably requires changes to the typer.

Comment: I really think you've overly focused on the API level; possibly that reflects your use case, but that isn't especially common in my experience.  Most Scala.js use cases wind up being maybe a few percent facade overall, and the rest of the code just uses those facades as clean types.  (Actually, that percentage is going steadily down as people share more facade libraries, so a growing number of apps using common APIs are simply picking up those libraries.)

Comment: @MaraisRossouw I have reverted your edit, since it did not correspond to the data in your question. If you want to edit it again, please edit all examples in the answer and the question.

Comment: @JustinduCoeur how could writing an SPA not have numerous api calls? Im working on an Angular (was hoping to move to Scala) where by it has 600~ different api endpoints it talks too.. Would I in this instance, not pick Scala due to the Facade issue?

Comment: Numerous API calls, sure.  Numerous endpoints -- sure, but *wow* that's by far the largest number I've ever seen in one app.  There's nothing peculiar about Scala in this case: any strongly-typed language is going to have the challenge of describing all of those endpoints properly.  But even then, I would expect the number of data structures involved to be much smaller: most apps reuse the same data structure repeatedly in many endpoints.

Comment: More importantly, though, this is the danger of being first. I mean, I was the first person to seriously use jQuery in the Scala.js environment, and I wound up putting some serious work into building a complete jQuery facade. Now that I've done so, everybody else uses jQuery easily and happily, but *somebody's* got to do the work. If no one has created a facade for your APIs (I assume you've looked), then you may be the trailblazer, I'm afraid. But there's nothing peculiar to Scala about this -- same is true for Typescript or any other language you need to adapt to...